# Returning the wrong type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this model of ProductPrice:

```
class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_size
  attr_accessible :current, :price, :product_id, :product_size_id, :since

  def self.get_product_prices(category_id, product_id)
    MenuCategory.find(category_id).product_sizes.each do |size|
      ProductPrice.find_or_create_by_product_size_id_and_product_id(size.id, product_id)
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `get_product_prices`, it returns the number of records correctly, but it returns ProductSize instead of ProductPrice.

How is it returning ProductSize instead of ProductPrice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using [each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each), and it returns the exact array which is applied, namely `MenuCategory.find(category_id).product_sizes`. Here is another example which may help you understand the problem:

```
def test
  [1, 3].each { |e| e * 2 }
end

test # => [1,3]
```

If you want it to return an array of ProductPrice, you may change `each` to `map`.